# Prove $(A \cup B) \oplus A = A - B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that $(A \cup B) \oplus A = A - B,$ where $\oplus$ is denoting the symmetric difference. I am trying to wrap my head around the problem and understand it but I am getting caught up on the fact that I can't properly visualize what $(A \cup B) \oplus A$ would look like. Any advice is appreciated.

Edit: It is possible that this is a false proof and I would have to provide sets showing so.

Comment: This seems incorrect to me. Let $b \in B$ with $b \not \in A$. Then $b \in A \cup B$ so $b \in (A \cup B) \oplus A$. But $b \not \in (A - B)$.

Comment: The right-hand side is reversed.

Comment: @hunter Yes, I just made an edit to the post. The proof may be false in which I would provide an example showing how - should've included that in the original posting.

Comment: What if $B$ is the empty set? What if $A$ is the empty set? Try these two obvious cases first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The members of the symmetric difference between two sets $C,D$ are precisely those things that are a member of one of the two sets but not of the other. Everything that is in $C$ but not in $D$ belongs to the symmetric difference, and everything that is in $D$ but not in $C$ belongs to the symmetric difference, and nothing else does.

Thus the members of the symmetric difference between $A\cup B$ and $A$ include everything that belongs to $A\cup B$ but not to $A$ and also everything that belongs to $A$ but not to $A\cup B.$

So that symmetric difference is $B\smallsetminus A.$

Comment: Thanks, that understanding of the symmetric difference really helped.

Answer (score 3):

Just apply the definitions to go from the new notation to previous notation, which might be easier for you to picture.

\begin{align*}
(A \cup B) \oplus A &= ((A \cup B) \smallsetminus A) \cup (A \smallsetminus (A \cup B))
\end{align*}
You may have an easier time visualizing this.  Also, the first term on the right-hand side should make it clear that something is reversed in your problem statement.